# Range Base loops for objects

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I want to use range base loops for objects , but it doesnt seem to work . here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class animal 
{
    public:
        animal ();
        void speak() {cout << "hi" ;}
};

int main()
{
    animal a;
    animal b;
    animal c;
    for ( animal * ptr : { &a , &b , &c } )
    {
        ptr->speak();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0286a16df920093b) fine for me (after adding in the missing default constructor definition). Maybe you should elaborate on *it doesn't seem to work*.

Comment: by the way this `{ &a , &b , &c }` is an `Initializer list` not "objects".

Comment: FWIW, I dislike that you iterate over pointers. Write a wrapper, `values`, which takes references of the objects and returns a `std::initializer_list<T&>` – that way you can iterate over `animal&` (or simpler, `auto&&`): `for (auto&& it : values(a, b, c)) …`

Comment: I dont know why I would need a wrapper , I can iterate over animal objects by using `for ( auto  ptr : { &a , &b , &c } )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a definition for your constructor:

```
animal () { }
```

Or remove it, since it doesn't do anything. The compiler will provide one for you.